# Deleting all but non-duplicates (racket)

Tags: duplicates, racket, abstraction, fold

I know how to make a function delete all duplicates, that's not my question though. I want to keep everything that is unique/ has no duplicates.

It would be especially good if someone could use abstraction/higher order functions in their response

So here's a few examples;

'(1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5) -> '(3 4 5)

'(1 1 1 2 2 2) -> empty

'(2 3 4) -> '(2 3 4)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298989/how-to-remove-all-the-duplicates-in-a-list-using-scheme-only-abstract-list-func

Comment: @soegaard not a duplicate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751559/how-to-remove-non-duplicate-elements-from-a-list-in-scheme

Comment: Still not a duplicate :( They're all very similar, and you can take from that what you want, but they are different problems being solved!

Comment: Easier to solve all four problems at the same time than to parse "all but non-predicate"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idiomatic `O(n)` solution in Racket, using [`bagify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741004/201359) and [iterations and comprehensions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html). The trick is counting how many occurrences are there of every element, and taking only those with exactly one:

```
(define (bagify lst)
  (foldl (lambda (key ht)
           (hash-update ht key add1 0))
         #hash() lst))

(define (non-dups lst)
  (for/list ([key+value (in-hash-pairs (bagify lst))]
             #:when (= (cdr key+value) 1))
    (car key+value)))
```

For example:

```
(non-dups '(1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4 5))
=> '(3 4 5)

(non-dups '(1 1 1 2 2 2))
=> '()

(non-dups '(2 3 4))
=> '(2 3 4)
```

Comment: @FateKyougo did any of the answers help you with your problem? please don't forget to give us some feedback ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#lang racket

(define (elements xs)
  (set->list (list->set xs)))

(define (duplicates xs)
  (elements
   (for/fold ([xs xs]) ([u (elements xs)])
     (remove u xs))))

(define (uniques xs)
  (remove* (duplicates xs) xs))

(define (remove-duplicates xs)
  (remove* (duplicates xs) xs))

(define (remove-non-duplicates xs)
  (remove* (uniques xs) xs))

(define xs  '(1 1 1 2 3 4 4))
(uniques xs)
(duplicates xs)
(remove-duplicates xs)
(remove-non-duplicates xs)
```

Output:

```
'(2 3)
'(4 1)
'(2 3)
'(1 1 1 4 4)
```