# How to find the number of repeated characters in list in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

i am trying to make a function in Scheme which returns how many times a character repeats in a list.
For example if i have (list 2 6 'a 'b 'a 'a 2)
the result must be ((2 . 2) (6 . 1) (a . 3) (b . 1))

it didnt need to be written in the most efficient way,just want to be easy and simple for understanding.

Thanks in advance for helping me :)

Comment: And what have you tried so far? please post the code you've written to solve this problem, pointing the exact part where you're having trouble

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count occurrence of element in a list in Scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740307/count-occurrence-of-element-in-a-list-in-scheme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this appears to be homework, you posted no code whatsoever, and we know nothing about your constraints and your current knowledge of Scheme, it's hard to answer.

Basically, you can do this efficiently with a hash map, or less efficiently with 2 nested loops. I'll explain the latter for you to get started.

I'll assume you know how to loop through the list.

So basically you need to

- 1) loop over your list

  - 2) for each element of the list (let's call it e)

    - 3) loop over the list once more, counting how many of (e) you find
    - 4) assemble (e) and the result of your counting loop

The results of step 4) need to be assembled in a result list.

If you do this, the result will be something like

```
'((2 . 2) (6 . 1) (a . 3) (b . 1) (a . 3) (a . 3) (2 . 2))
```

which is close... but not correct because you counted some elements a few times.

So in addition to the above you need a way of keeping track of every element you already encountered, and steps 3) and 4) need to be done only if you encounter a new element. Keeping track could be through another list, or simply by checking your current result list, depending on your code.

If you have any code to show, please update your question and we can help more.

**EDIT**

OK, since GoZoner has posted code, I have 2 alternative versions for you. I hope you study all of these and make up your own mind, instead of simply copying one.

First, the version I described; as opposed to GoZoner's version, it does not use *mutable* lists but is slower than the mutable version:

```
(define (how-many lst)
  (let loop ((lst2 lst) (res '()))
    (if (empty? lst2)
        (reverse res)
        (let ((c (car lst2)))
          (loop (cdr lst2) 
                (if (assoc c res) 
                    res 
                    (cons (cons c (count (lambda (e) (eq? e c)) lst)) res)))))))

=> '((2 . 2) (6 . 1) (a . 3) (b . 1))
```

If you want to use a mutable structure (and I would, too), I recommend mutable hash tables. The following example is in Racket but is trivial to adapt to R6RS Scheme [hash tables](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-14.html) if required:

```
(define (how-many lst)
  (let ((res (make-hash)))
    (for-each (lambda (e) (hash-update! res e add1 0)) lst)
    (hash->list res)))

=> '((6 . 1) (a . 3) (b . 1) (2 . 2))
```

Just note that hash tables do not respect order, so you'll get the same result but the pairs will probably in a different order (and even vary from one call to the next).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
(define (character-count list)
  (assert (list? list))
  (let looking ((list list) (rslt '()))
    (cond ((null? list) rslt)
          ((assoc (car list) rslt) =>
           (lambda (pair) 
             (set-cdr! pair (+ 1 (cdr pair)))
             (looking (cdr list) rslt)))
          (else (looking (cdr list) 
                         (cons (cons (car list) 1) rslt))))))
> (character-count '(2 a 2 a b c 2))
((c . 1) (b . 1) (a . 2) (2 . 3))
```

I get an 'A'?!

Comment: can you tell me what is assert doing?