# Frequency List in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I want to write a function for finding how many times each element occurs in a list. For example for the list `'(1 1 1 2 2 3 4)`, 1 occurs thrice, 2 occurs twice, and 3 and 4 both occur once. So the output should be like 
`((1 3) (2 2) (3 1) (4 1))`. Here's the code I wrote:

```
(define (aa-helper list counter)
  (cond [(null? list) '()]
        [(eq? (car list) (cadr list)) (aa-helper (cdr list) (+ counter 1))]
        [else (cons (car list) counter) (aa-helper (cdr list) 1)]))

(define (aa list)
  (aa-helper list 1))
```

But I got this error:

> ```
> cadr: contract violation
>   expected: (cons/c any/c pair?)
>   given: '(4)
> ```

Comment: When you know list is null you do car. When list is a pair you have no guarantee (cdr list) is a pair thus you should check that before doing cadr.

Comment: @Oscar Lopez if you know really well you can answer my question.Right?

Comment: @ayshee Óscar is referring to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5741004/13), in which I answer that question in multiple ways, depending on your performance and/or portability requirements. Because there are multiple ways to solve it, there's no point repeating the answer in this thread.