# Number of same atomic elements in a list like (a (a b) (b c))

Tags: recursion, numbers, scheme

I would like to ask you for help with the following:

When I apply a procedure number-of-elements on the list, I need to get a list of pairs, where on the first place in the pair is the element and on the second place (after the dot) there is a number of elements occurred in the list.

For example, when typing this:

```
(number-of-elements '((a b c) a (b c) c (a b b)))
```

I got this:

```
((a . 3) (b . 4) (c . 3))
```

So far I have a code working on regular list (a b a d).

```
(define number-of-elements
 (lambda (lst)
  (define exclude
  (lambda (sznm key)
    (foldr (lambda (ass result)
             (if (equal? (car ass) key)
                 result
                 (cons ass result)))
           '()
           sznm)))
(foldr (lambda (key bag)
         (cond ((assoc key bag)
                => (lambda (old)
                     (let ((new (cons key (+ (cdr old) 1))))
                       (cons new (exclude bag key)))))
               (else (let ((new (cons key 1)))
                       (cons new bag)))))
       '()
       lst)))
```

But if I use it on:

```
(number-of-elements '((a b c) a (b c) c (a b b)))
```

I got this:

```
(((a b c) . 1) (a . 1) ((b c) . 1) (c . 1) ((a b b) . 1))
```

I know I need to use a deep recursion, but I do not know, how to implement it into the code I actually have.

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, pointing specific problems with the implementation.

Comment: I posted the code you asked me for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already did most of the work counting the elements - but see the different implementations of [`bagify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741004/201359) for a simpler implementation. One straightforward solution for dealing with nested sublists would be to `flatten` the input list before counting the elements:

```
(number-of-elements
 (flatten
  '((a b c) a (b c) c (a b b))))

=> '((a . 3) (b . 4) (c . 3))
```

If your interpreter doesn't define `flatten`, it's easy to implement:

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (if (not (list? lst))
      (list lst)
      (apply append (map flatten lst))))
```

This is the idiomatic way to think about solutions in Scheme: decompose the problem in parts, then use built-in procedures to solve each subpart, and finally combine them.

Comment: Great, now it works :-) I just put a little bit more code in order not to need to write (number-of-elements (flatten '(..., but only the first procedure.

Comment: I like your implementation of `flatten` :)