# count number of element in multiple sublists scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

i would like to ask you for help with my task i am trying to solve. Function should work like this. Input is sublist `((1 10 250) (1 10 250) (250 10 250) (1 10 255)))` and output should be `((1 . 3) (10 . 4) (250 . 4) (255 . 1))` so it output is actually histogram in text format.

I am using this code with implementation of `flatten` function which is making from sublists one list. But it is counting number of sublists and not every element in sublist.

```
 (define (run-length-encode lst )
    (define (rle val-lst cur-val cur-cnt acc)
        (if (pair? val-lst)
          (let ((new-val (car val-lst)))
           (if (eq? new-val cur-val)
              (rle (cdr val-lst) cur-val (+ cur-cnt 1) acc)
              (rle (cdr val-lst) new-val 1 (cons (cons cur-cnt cur-val) acc))))
        (cons (cons cur-cnt cur-val) acc)))
          (if (pair? lst)
           (reverse (rle (cdr lst) (car lst) 1 '()))
           '()))
```

**Flatten function:**

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (if (not (list? lst))
      (list lst)
      (apply append (map flatten lst))))
```

**Output:**

```
> (run-length-encode '((1 10 250) (1 10 250) (250 10 250) (1 10 255)))
(250 10 1 1 250 10 1 1 250 10 250 1 255 10 1 1)
```

Thanks for help on this.
Jan

Comment: I corrected the code

Comment: Yes i corrected parenthesis only. I am sorry but probably i dont understand what do you want to tell me :). Output is still wrong. I would like to have output like `((1 . 3) (10 . 4) (250 . 4) (255 . 1))` . I thought if i will use `flatten` function it will omit parenthesis from result and after that i can process is like normal list.

Comment: I just thought you posted the code that didn't work at all. I was mistaken about that. It works, just produces a wrong output. Right now your question is "my code doesn't work as expected. Why?" and it's not much fun to work with. Try breaking your code up into smaller pieces, testing and verifying those, and then build the solution from them. this way, if you have problems on the way, you have a specific pointed question. If your language is too restrictive, try finding the answer in full racket first, then translate it down.

Comment: I've tested your new code, and it does work correctly, actually. It produces the correct results. You just need to call it as `(run-length-encode ... ...  '((1 10 250) (1 10 250) (250 10 250) (1 10 255)))` where you should put something on each of the `...`. Can you tell what to put there? For example, have you tried `(run-length-encode '(1 10 250 1 10 250 250 10 250 1 10 255))`? Have you tried `(run-length-encode '(1 1 1 1 10 250 250 250))`?

Comment: don't hesitate to ask if you need another hint, or an answer altogether.

Comment: well it works like run-length-encode but i actually want to have it working in another way. So if input is  `((1 10 250) (1 10 250) (250 10 250) (1 10 255)))` so i want ot have ouptut like `((1 . 3) (10 . 4) (250 . 4) (255 . 1))`. Output is not run-lenght-encode its like histogram output. So count of each element in the list are counted ant then inserted to dotted list. Now it count's for instance (1 10 230) as one elemet but there are three.

Comment: I showed you an expression with ... ... in it. You need to put something on each of the dots, to make it work like you need it to. I know it's possible, because I did it, and it worked. Have you tried the expressions I provided? I expected you to get some insight after running them.

Answer (score 1):

In Racket there's a built-in [`flatten`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._flatten%29%29) procedure, there's no need to rewrite it. Coupled with good old [`bagify`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741004/201359), we can solve the problem using simple procedure composition - you should avoid trying to do everything in a single procedure, it'll be confusing:

```
#lang racket

(define (bagify lst)
  (foldl (lambda (key ht)
           (hash-update ht key add1 0))
         #hash() lst))

(define (run-length-encode lst)
  (hash->list
   (bagify (flatten lst))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(run-length-encode '((1 10 250) (1 10 250) (250 10 250) (1 10 255)))
=> '((1 . 3) (250 . 4) (10 . 4) (255 . 1))
```

Comment: Problem is i can't use buit-in flatten and or hash its giving me this `error hash->list: undefined;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition`

Comment: It's ok if you want to use your own `flatten`. For using hashes, make sure that `#lang racket` is the first line of your file, and select the option "determine language from source". If this `bagify` implementation doesn't work for you, check the linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741004/201359), there are several options and one of them should work for you.

Comment: I have to use Pretty Big language so it doesnot works for me unfortunatelly.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it’s a pretty limited language :( . But my main advice remains - split the problem in parts, and write a separate procedure to count the frequencies.