# Counting number of occurrences of elements in a list

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, swap, r5rs

I am writing a function called count-if, which takes in a predicate, p?, and a list, ls. The function returns the number of occurrences of elements in the nested list that satisfy p?
For example: (count-if (lambda (x) (eq? 'z x))  '((f x) z (((z x c v z) (y))))) will return 3. This is what I have written:

```
(define (count-if p ls) (cond
  ((null? ls) '())
  ((p (car ls))
    (+ 1 (count-if p (cdr ls))))
  (else
    (count-if p (cdr ls)))))
```

But I just get an error. I could use some help finding a better way to go about this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count occurrence of element in a list in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740307/count-occurrence-of-element-in-a-list-in-scheme)

Answer (score 0):

What is the signature of `count-if`? It is:

```
[X] [X -> Boolean] [List-of X] -> Number
```

What does the first `cond` clause return? It returns:

```
'()
```

This is a simple type error. Just change the base case to `0` and `count-if` works.

---

**Edit** (for nested).

First we define the structure of the date as `Nested`. 
A symbol is just fed into the `score` helper function. Otherwise the recursive call is applied on all nested sub-`nested`s, and the results are summed up.

```
#lang racket

; Nested is one of:
; - Number
; - [List-of Nested]

; Nested -> Number
(define (count-if pred inp)
  ; Symbol -> Number
  (define (score n) (if (pred n) 1 0))
  ; Nested -> Number
  (define (count-if-h inp)
    (if (symbol? inp)
        (score inp)
        (apply + (map count-if-h inp))))
  (count-if-h inp))


(count-if (lambda (x) (eq? 'z x)) '((f x) z (((z x c v z) (y)))))
; => 3
```

Comment: I changed that and I'm not getting an error, but I'm not getting the right number returned. Now I'm having some trouble getting a count from the nested lists also. I know I need to check if the first item is a list but not sure where to go after that.

Comment: Hey, I overlooked the nested lists. Added.